# How to use ngClass with css?

Tags: angular, ng-class

I have a css code that looks like this:

```css
:host >>> a.ng2-smart-sort-link.sort::after {
    content: '';
    right: 0.75rem;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom-color: #1a2138;
    border-bottom: solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    border-left: solid transparent;
    border-right: solid transparent;
    border-width: 0.375rem;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%) rotate(180deg);
    transform: translate(0, -50%) rotate(180deg);
  }

 a.sort.asc::after {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
 }
```

```html
 <ng2-smart-table [ngClass]="{class: settings.columns.device.showSortIcon == true}"></ng2-smart-table>
```

How can I implement a class in css to use it with ngClass to display this css if a condition is true?

Comment: did you check any of the answers ? 

Answer (score 1):

Use `className` to toggle your css class. If your css class name is `class` then :

```
<ng2-smart-table [className.class]="{!!settings.columns.device.showSortIcon }"</ng2-smart-table>
```

Or angular directive `ngClass` :

```
<ng2-smart-table [ngClass]="{'class': !!settings.columns.device.showSortIcon }"</ng2-smart-table>
```

I tend to prefer `className` when I only have one conditional class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ng2-smart-table [ngClass]="{'class':settings.columns.device.showSortIcon == true}"</ng2-smart-table>
```

Answer (score 0):

ngClass directive will add the class to the element it self so the class selector will be like this

```
:host >>> component-tag.calss .. {
  // something magical will happen ‍♂️
}
```

> **ngClass** Class will add the class base of the condition is true

as an example consider this

template

```
<app-title [ngClass]="{'blue-text' : color === 'blue', 'green-text' : color == 'green'}">
</app-title>
```

style

```
:host >>> app-title.blue-text p {
  color: blue
}
:host >>> app-title.green-text p {
  color: green
}
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mnhnti)

Comment: It dosen't work (this is the change I made`[ngClass]="{'sort' : settings.columns.device.showSortIcon === true}"`). I want to execute the css code if the condition is true (in typescript) to show a sort arrow on the header of a table. But if I change the condition in typescript to false it also show the icon.

Comment: have you try like this `:host >>> ng2-smart-table.sort a.ng2-smart-sort-link.sort::after  {}` ? share with us the style file @mihai003